# Was this down to a previously absorbed trouble?

Tags: haven

Spoilers for the Haven finale.

During the first part *Now*:

> Nathan killed Duke to prevent the troubles he had absorbed being passed to Croatoan

And later, during the second part *Forever*:

> Duke appeared as a spirit to help guide Dwight and Nathan

**How was Duke able to do this? Was this a trouble he had absorbed?**

Comment: A lot of what happened not just in the finale, but much of the run up to it, didn't make much sense to me. In the first couple of seasons, the troubles were an inexplicable supernatural phenomenon. As such, they didn't require any logic to account for their existence, occurrence, or manifestation, and you could just suspend your disbelief and go with it. Then the writers introduced Mara and started trying to explain the true nature of the troubles. That's when I found it progressively harder and harder to suspend disbelief and inconsistencies seemed to pop up faster than new troubles.

Comment: Yes. It becomes more and more strange. I wonder if the writers made up anything of it before they started the first season. Regarding Duke, I think it was not a trouble. He just ascended or something like that.